# How to differentiate between status code of IIS and status code of Web API Application

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, apm

take following endpoint as a service that return the user info based on it's id

```
/getUser?id=1234
```

How can the client or a monitor tool differentiate that the user whom id = 1234 is not exist from that user requesting a page that is not exist?

the same problem I have for all status code e.g 500 my infrastructure team told me that you report misleading information as they are not able to differentiate from 500 sourced from my service and 500 that is sourced from the server itself IIS

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good question.

Most tutorials will happily tell you to return NotFound which is 404. I guess those people never had to build AND support a production level API.

You need to have some conventions and stick to them. I prefer to return 204 instead of 404. 204 means the calls succeeded but there was no content. This way you will have a clear difference between *data does not exist* and *endpoint does not exist*.

As for 500, your API should never return 500 unless something really bad and unrecoverable happened, server side. I would advise against happily throwing exceptions for everything. If your business rules are not satisfied, that's no reason to throw anything. If your API cannot access your database, that would require a 500 to make it obvious something really bad happened. As for your reported 500 issue, I do not agree with that. IIS has its own logs, your service will have its own logs so yes, your infrastructure team can differentiate.

Comment: Except the fact that IIS itself never returns 500.0, this answer covers most https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 The infrastructure team should be able to distinguish when they analyze IIS log files (with sub-status in entries), but over the wire everyone only see status code 500 (the body varies).